# Function that returns disjoint sublists

Tags: functions

I have to write a function that takes two arguments: a list *list* and an integer *n*. The function should return another list called *result* with sublists of length *n*. These sublists should contain all variations of elements from *list*, with no duplicates. Could someone help me how to approach this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does `Subsets[list, {n}]` do what you need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a list of numbers without duplicates. You want to create all sublists with given length, where the order matters and no duplicates in the sublist are allowed, for short: variations without repetition.

For safety, we first make sure that the original list contains no duplicates. Then we create all sublists with length n. Finally we create all permutations of the sublists:

```
variations[list_, n_] := Module[{d = Union[list]},
  d = Subsets[d, {n}];
  Flatten[Permutations /@ d, 1]
]
```

Here is a small test:

```
dat = Range[5];
variations[dat, 3]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a ton, works perfectly fine!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Permutations`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Permutations.html) directly using the second argument to specify the length of sublists:

```
ClearAll[duplicateFreePermutations]

duplicateFreePermutations[lst_, n_] := Permutations[Union @ lst, {n}]
```

***Examples:***

```
duplicateFreePermutations[Range[5], 3]
```

[image]

```
duplicateFreePermutations[{a, b, b, c, c}, 3]
```

> ```
> {{a, b, c}, {a, c, b}, {b, a, c}, {b, c, a}, {c, a, b}, {c, b, a}}
> ```